# How to display a message when _.each(list) is empty in underscorejs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I'm building an small web app which uses underscorejs as a template engine. I have the following code in my template:

```
  <% _.each(tracks, function(track){ %>
      <div class="title"><%= track.title %></div>
  <% }) ; %>
```

If 'tracks' is empty, how can I display a 'No tracks available' message instead using underscorejs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd just check the length, and use a condition

```
<% if ( tracks.length ) {
       _.each(tracks, function(track){ %>
          <div class="title"><%= track.title %></div>
       <% }); 
    } else {
       %> <div class="empty">No tracks available</div> <%
    }
%>
```